# How to do something after the login with Spring Security?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-saml

I have a Spring web application which uses Spring SAML and Spring Security to manage the login process. 
Now I need to do some tasks after the correct login occurs. In particular I have to store some data in the `SecurityContext.getContext()` object.

I have never worked with Spring Security/SAML and I don't know how it manages the return from the IdP.

Is there any place in the code where usually you can put your code after the login process ends correctly?

I mean, I know where the redirect page is set but I cannot put my custom code in the Controller of this redirect page because that page is accessed more than one time, and I need to run my custom code only once at login time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best approach is to implement interface `SAMLUserDetailsService`, which will automatically store object you return from its `loadUserBySAML` method in the `Authentication` object which you can later query from the `SecurityContext.getContext()`. The interface is called once after each authentication. See [the manual](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security-saml/1.0.x-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#configuration-authentication-object) for details and examples.

The other possibility is `AuthenticationSuccessHandler`. The login process calls method onAuthenticationSuccess which has access to the `Authentication` object, which will be stored in the SecurityContext.getContext().

Simply create your own class which implements interface `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` (you can also extend some of the existing classes, such as `SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler` or `AbstractAuthenticationTargetUrlRequestHandler`). Then plug your implementation to the `securityContext.xml` by changing class in the existing `successRedirectHandler` bean.

The problem is, that the `Authentication` object tends to be immutable - so the first way might be better.

Answer (score 4):

You can use AuthenticationSuccessEvent. Just register a bean that implements ApplicationListener.

```
    @Component
    public class SomeSpringBean implements
                             ApplicationListener<AuthenticationSuccessEvent> {

        public onApplicationEvent(AuthenticationSuccessEvent event) {
           String userName = ((UserDetails) event.getAuthentication().
           //do stuff                                       
        }
   }
```

And you need to register AuthenticationEventPublisher.
Take a look here: https://gist.github.com/msarhan/10834401

If you use custom authentication provider, you can also plug whatever you want there.

Comment: Thank you for the response Evgeni. In my WebSecurityConfig I have this bean definition http://pastebin.com/cqBXdu2W 

As you can see it already defines a Authentication Success Handler method. The problem is that if I recall the SecurityContext in the successRedirectHandler() method, it is null

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Spring's Java configs?

If so, then you probably have a class that overrides WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter in your project.  Extending this class gives you access to override the method configure(HttpSecurity http).

You can use that provided HttpSecurity builder object to configure a lot of things, one of which is the authentication success handler.  More or less, you can create a simple that class that implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler (Spring has a few classes already built for extension to make this easy), and you can call http.successHandler(yourSuccessHandler) to register it with Spring Security.

Implementing that interface gives you the hook to put custom code into the onAuthenticationSuccess( ... ) method.  I think they have one for failures as well.

Comment: Thank you npm622. Will the SecurityContext be already set when the AuthenticationSuccessHandler method will be called? My problem is this: I need a place to put my custom code in which the SecurityContext is already set by the Spring SAML module

Comment: Yeah...should be.  Check out Spring's SecurityContextHolder class, it has a static method to access the current security context.