# how to get the saml authenticated token in my custom filter using Spring Security

Tags: spring-security, spring-saml

I need  the authentication details as user name and email id in my filter before the user redirected to home page/required page.
i need this user details for doing a some extra validation
Any help is valuable.

Comment: Vladimir!! By implementing SAMLUserDetailsService I get the user details, I have a question if i want to store the user details and after redirecting to (by successRedirectHandler) a filter and I need the user details to do some process, how can I achive it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See information about `AuthneticationSuccessHandler` and `SAMLUserDetailsService` for Spring SAML [in answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28903188/how-to-do-something-after-the-login-with-spring-security).

Comment: Thanks Vladimir!!  By implementing  SAMLUserDetailsService I get the user details,

Comment: My pleasure, just comment further if it doesn't fully cover what you need to get done. Once you're happy with the answer, please accept it, so it's clear there was an adequate solution provided. Welcome to Stackoverflow!

Comment: Vladimir!!  By implementing  SAMLUserDetailsService I get the user details, I have a question if i want to store the user details and after redirecting to   (by successRedirectHandler) a filter and I need the user details to do some process, how can I achive it.

Comment: You can get the object you stored using SAMLUserDetailsService by calling SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getDetails()